# error in mail functionality in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

Im working with laravel 5.3. In that i have mail functionality the variable get after the mail function is not working, below is my controller coding

```
public function checkEmail(Request $request) {
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $users = Student::where('email', $email)->select('email')->first();

    if(count($users) > 0){
        $id =Student::where('email',$email )->value('id');

        $url=url('/').'/password-reset/'.$id;

        Mail::send('/resetpassword', ['email'=>$email,'url'=>$url ], function($message)
        { 
           $message->to(Input::get('email'))->subject('Reset Password');
        });
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Link has been sent to your Mail');
    } else {   
        return redirect()->back()->with(['message' => 'No Records Found']);    
    }
}
```

I got all the variable values before mail function (i.e.,)

> Mail::send('/resetpassword', ['email'=>$email,'url'=>$url ], function($message)
>               { 
>                  $message->to(Input::get('email'))->subject('Reset Password');
>               });

I got error like this

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found

if i use any variable the error is like this

> Undefined Variable:url

Please anyone tellme what i did wrong...